# JPA mapping ManyToMany with common column in composite foreign keys

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, join, many-to-many

I've these tables in my Oracle database (which I can't change):

| Table_A | Table_B | Table_AB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID (PK) | ID_B (PK) | ID_A (PK) |
| COMMON_ID (PK) | COMMON_ID (PK) | B_ID (PK) |
| ... | ... | COMMON_ID (PK) |

Tables A and B have a many-to-many relationship and Table AB contains two foreign keys:

- **FK_1**: ID_A, COMMON_ID referencing table A (ID, COMMON_ID)
- **FK_2**: B_ID, COMMON_ID referencing table B (ID_B, COMMON_ID)

I tried to map these table but I have a problem in my jointable due the fact column "COMMON_ID" is shared between FK_1 e FK_2. Hibernate in fact tries to create the jointable with two column with the same name, generating this exception:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column mapping for collection: B.collectionA column: COMMON_ID
```

These are my entities, please can anyone help me to solve the problem? Thank you in advance!

**Entity A**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Table_A")
@IdClass(value = A_PK.class)
public class A implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2210864155927195752L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "TABLE_A_SEQ", sequenceName = "TABLE_A_PKSEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "TABLE_A_SEQ")
    private long id;
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="COMMON_ID")
    private Integer commonId;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "TABLE_AB",
            joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "ID_A", referencedColumnName = "ID"),
                @JoinColumn(name = "COMMON_ID", referencedColumnName = "COMMON_ID")
            },
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "B_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID_B"),
                @JoinColumn(name = "COMMON_ID", referencedColumnName = "COMMON_ID")
            }
    )
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<B> collectionB;

    getter, setter, hashcode, equals
```

**Entity A_PK**:

```
public class A_PK implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private long id;
    private Integer commonId;

    getter, setter, hashcode, equals
```

**Entity B**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TABLE_B")
@IdClass(value = B_PK.class)
public class B implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5761968943282358603L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_B", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "TABLE_B_SEQ", sequenceName = "TABLE_B_PKSEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "TABLE_B_SEQ")
    private Long id;
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="COMMON_ID")
    private Integer commonId;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "collectionB")
    private List<A> collectionA;

    getter, setter, hashcode, equals
```

**Entity B_PK**:

```
public class B_PK implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private Long id;
    private Integer commonId;

    getter, setter, hashcode, equals
```